# how i make a condition with ajax and asp mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to put a condition if the user want to add a second appointment he receives an alert

```
                     function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

this is my code in controller :

```
                                       public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
    {
        var status = false;

        if (e.EventID > 0)
        {
            //Update the event
            var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;
                v.StartDate = e.StartDate;
                v.EndDate = e.EndDate;
                v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                v.EventID = e.EventID;
                v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;

            }

            else

            db.Events.Add(e);
            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
```

i want to make the user add one time his event and receive an alert i try but not work

Answer (score 0):

I think i can help:

```
     if(Session["appointment"] != "ok")<>
      {
        if (e.EventID > 0)
        {
            //Update the event
            var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;
                v.StartDate = e.StartDate;
                v.EndDate = e.EndDate;
                v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                v.EventID = e.EventID;
                v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;

            }

            else

            db.Events.Add(e);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Session["appointment"] = "ok";

            return JSON(new{appointment="ok"});
        }
}else
{
      return JSON(new {appointment="no-good");
}
```

and controller:

function SaveEvent(data)
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.appointment == "ok")
                    {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                    else {  your msg error here     }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
        }
    })

dont not forget Session.Clear();
as the user logs out